# Having problems searching with strings from csv module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file `partList.csv` with strings that I want to use to search through a larger group of txt files.  For some reason when I use the direct string '*L 99*' I get a result.  When I load the string *L 99* from the csv I get no result.

`partList.csv` only contains cells in the first column with part numbers, one of which is *L-99*.  `txt_files_sample\5.txt` is a text document that at some point contains the string *L 99*

My code:

```
def GetPartList():
    partList = []
    f = open('partList.csv', 'rb')
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            part = row[0].replace('-',' ').strip()
            partList.append(part)
    finally:
        f.close()
    return partList

def FindFileNames(partList):
    i = 0
    files = []
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('txt_files_sample'):
        for f in filenames:
            document = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'rb')
            for line in document:
                if partList[i] in line:
                #if 'L 99' in line:
                    files.append(f)
                    break
            i = i + 1
    return files

print FindFileNames(GetPartList())
```

The code, as it stands above produces:

```
>>> []
```

If I uncomment `if 'L 99' in line:` and comment out `if partList[i] in line:` I get the result:

```
>>> ['5.txt']
```

Comment: Why are you using `i` then to index `partList`? You are testing each element in `partList` against a *different file*. What does `partList` contain here?

Comment: Yeah I've been looking at that myself.  I'm going to make an edit, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

So using [Martijn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) input, I discovered the issue was how I looped over `partList`.  Rewritting `FindFileNames()` worked:

```
def FindFileList(partList):
    i = 0
    files = []
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('txt_files'):
        for f in filenames:
            a = 0
            document = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'rb')
            for line in document:
                if a is 1:
                    break
                for partNo in partList:
                    if partNo in line:
                        files.append(f)
                        a = 1
            document.close()
    return files
```

With the updated code I got a result that was an accurate list of filenames.

Comment: You are not closing the files and maybe factoring the search into an own function and returning as soon as any part number is found in a line makes this more efficient.  Or even correct, because right now a file with more than one part number in it will be added more than once to the list of files.